# How can I filter a dataframe of dates with other date in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, date, dataframe, filtering

I have this dataframe in python done in pandas:

```
        0
0   2018-06-29
1   2018-10-29
2   2019-02-28
3   2019-06-29
4   2019-10-29
5   2020-02-29
6   2020-06-29
7   2020-10-29
8   2021-02-28
```

Then I have a date that is the next one:

```
[datetime.date(2020, 2, 29)]
```

I want to filter the data frame to get just the dates that are <= that the date I have. I tried this with loc[] but I get the next output:

```
Seleccion = df.loc[df[0] < date]
Arrays were different lengths: 9 vs 1
```

I don't know if there is a way to do that, but if it is, any help would be perfect.
Thank you for taking your time.

Comment: You don't need the `.iloc` just do `selection = df[df['0'] < date]`

Comment: The output is the same @TBurgis

Comment: See the answer below. My comment is correct.

Answer (score 1):

What is the value of "date" on your example?
If it is

```
date = [datetime.date(2020, 2, 29)]
```

then it is normal the error is happening because you are comparing a series to an array.

What you want to do is

```
date = datetime.date(2020, 2, 29)
df[df[0] < date]
```

because now you are comparing a Series with a constant, and pandas is able to transform it into a comparison row-wise over the Series.

Before you were comparing a Series with an array (even if it has a single element), and for that to work, the array had to have the same length as the Series.

Comment: You have a typo in `df.[df[0] < date]`, get rid of the `.`

Comment: That works but if there a way to convert the array in a datetime.date object? @TBurgis

Comment: Which variable are you calling "the array"? I assumed the datatype of df[0] was a datetime.date object.
If you need to convert it use the pd.to_datetime and then look into [link](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#time-date-components).